# Jquery Closest and Parents Not Working with Input and Nested Divs

Tags: jquery, html, traversal, closest, parents

I have hidden Divs with ".display-link" classes that are two levels up from an input box. When an input (checkbox) is clicked, it should display the hidden link in the parent's previous sibling's wrapper.

Or another way to say it is, when an input checkbox is clicked it should find the previous div with the class .display-link and show() that.

I am having trouble traversing the elements to reach this div with this class. It should only display the one, previous div.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<head>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>
<script>

$(document).ready(function(){

$(".display-link").hide();//hide all links

$('input').click (function ()
    {
    $(this).closest(".display-link").show();//doesn't work
    $(this).closest("div.display-link").show();//doesn't work
    myInput = $(this);
    $(myInput).closest(".display-link").show();//doesn't work
    $(myInput).parents(".display-link").show();//doesn't work
    $(myInput).prevUntil(".display-link").show();//doesn't work
    });
});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<div class="accordion-button">First Heading
  <div class="display-link">LINK</div>
</div>
<div class="collapsible">
  <div class="input-row">
    <input id="checkbox01" name="checkbox01" type="checkbox" value="value01"  />
    <label for="checkbox01" >Name 1</label>
  </div>
  <div class="input-row">
    <input id="checkbox02" name="checkbox02" type="checkbox" value="value02"  />
    <label for="checkbox02" >Name 2</label>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="accordion-button">Second Heading
  <div class="display-link">LINK</div>
</div>
<div class="collapsible">
  <div class="input-row">
    <input id="checkbox03" name="checkbox03" type="checkbox" value="value03"  />
    <label for="checkbox03" >Name 3</label>
  </div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

I need to go out of the collapsible div and into the accordion-button div down to the display-link div.

Comment: What's the CSS for display-link?

Comment: Thanks for all of the solutions everyone. I appreciate it!!!

Comment: @Diodeus, the class is just a selector I am using to grab hold of the link. Since you asked, it floats:right. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('input').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('.collapsible').prev('.accordion-button').children('.display-link').show();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hazvX/

This finds the parent `.collapsible` element, finds the previous `.accordion-button` element, then selects it's child `.display-link` element.

Your HTML shows that there are two `.display-link` elements and three inputs. If you want the inputs to find the first possible (previous) `.display-link` elements you can use `.prevAll()` in place of `.prev()`:

```
$('input').on('click', function () {
    $(this).parents('.collapsible').prevAll('.accordion-button').eq(0).children('.display-link').show();
});
```

Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/hazvX/1/

Notice I also added `.eq(0)` after the `.prevAll()` function to only get the first returned element (since there can be multiple).

Note that `.on()` is new in jQuery 1.7 and in this case is the same thing as `.bind()`.

Answer (score 1):

Since the `.display-link` element you want to display is not a sibling or an ancestor of the checkbox you can't do this in one step. First go up to the `.collapsible` element which is a sibling of `.accordion-button`, then get the previous element, which is `.accordion-button` itself, and then find the `.display-link` element within that:

```
$(":checkbox").click(function() {
    $(this).closest(".collapsible").prev().find("display-link").show();
});
```

The `closest` method only looks at ancestor elements, as does `parents`. The `prevUntil` method only looks at preceding siblings.

Note that the above will only work if your structure stays as it is in the question. If you add elements in places that would affect the above code you will have to modify it accordingly. You could make it a bit more robust if you think the DOM may change:

```
$(this).closest(".collapsible").prevAll(".accordion-button:first").find(".display-link").show();
```

Comment: You're example is missing some periods to denote class selectors.

Comment: @Jasper - Thanks, well spotted. My `.` key is suffering after a recent spill on my keyboard :(

Answer (score 0):

Parents, closest won't work because it isn't in the same path.

Can you give them an ID, or put them in another container:
http://jsfiddle.net/Cq9Cw/

Comment: I don't totally get what you're trying to say, but in your demo using `.closest()` and `.parents()` results in the same outcome. The difference in the two functions is that `.parents()` will return an array of elements if more than one is found, `.closest()` will only get the first match (`.closest()` == `.parents().eq(0)`)

Answer (score -1):

Another solution I'll throw in here, is if each input had a corresponding display-link then you could use the index

http://jsfiddle.net/7TaqC/

Now of course in your example there are 3 inputs and only 2 links, however I don't know if this is because this is just a small snippet of your code

```
$(".display-link").hide();//hide all links

$('input').click (function (e)
{
   $this = $(this);
var index = $('input').index($this);
$('.display-link').eq(index).show();

});
```

Comment: The HTML in the question does not have the same number of `.display-link` and `input` elements. There are three `input` elements and two `.display-link` elements.

Comment: I know, I did mention that in my answer, I said if each one has a corresponding display-link as I wanted to make sure he didn't just leave a snippet of code.